Am I taking the antiderivative of $|x|$ correctly?
Note: originally posted on math.codidact. It currently has [+3/-0] (score of 0.7142857) with 0 answers after ~24 hours.
So I remember seeing this video by Blackpenredpen on the Youtube homepage around 3 months ago where he was showing failed attempts of him trying to figure out how to get$$\int\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}dx=\int|\sin(x)|dx=-\cot(x)|\sin(x)|+c$$without piecewise integration.
While I do have my own attempts at this that I've done over the course of 2 months (by attempting IBP or using $u$-substitution), I think these attempts have failed because I don't really understand how to even evaluate$$\int|x|dx$$So I think that if I can integrate this, I can integrate$$\int|\sin(x)|dx$$using a similar method. Here is my attempt at doing so:
We have that$$\int|x|dx=\int1\cdot|x|dx$$Now, we can rewrite this as$$\int\left(\frac d{dx}x\right)|x|dx$$and now we can use IBP.
Here's a brief overview of IBP for anyone who doesn't remember it:

IBP, which stands for Integration By Parts, is a method of integration that states that for functions f(x) and g(x),$$\int f(x)dg(x)=f(x)g(x)-\int g(x)df(x)$$(here $dg(x)$ and $df(x)$ means $\frac d{dx}g(x)$ and $\frac d{dx}f(x)$ respectively. I understand the notation is disliked a lot)So what I think it is trying to show here in this context is that if we can rewrite our integral as a product of a 2 functions, and we know the antiderivative of one of them, we can use that to find the antiderivative of the other function.

So now we can use IBP on our integral$$I=\int\left(\frac d{dx}x\right)|x|dx$$using$$f(x)=|x|\\g(x)=x$$to get$$I=\int\left(\frac d{dx}x\right)|x|=x|x|-\int x\cdot\left(\frac{|x|}x\right)dx\\=x|x|-\int|x|dx\\I=x|x|-\int|x|dx\implies I=x|x|-I\\\implies 2I=x|x|\implies I=\int|x|dx=\frac{x|x|}2$$So we have that the antiderivative of $|x|$ is $\frac{x|x|}2+C$.
However, my question is: Am I taking the antiderivative of |x| correctly, or how would I take it?

In your integration by parts, you have tried to take the derivative of a function that is not everywhere differentiable; specifically, $\lvert x \rvert$ is not differentiable at $0$. Avoiding this gives piecewise integration, which sounds exactly like what the original inspiration was trying to avoid.

How about simply considering the function piecewise and then merging the result in the end?

In your brief overview of IBP, to match what you did, instead $dg(x)$ and $df(x)$ would be $\left(\frac{d}{dx}g(x)\right)\color{red}{dx}$ and $\left(\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)\color{red}{dx}$ respectively.

If you don't want to use a piecewise approach, then you will be confronted with the derivative of $f(x) = |x|$ one way or another, which doesn't exists at the origin obviously. In most applications, this problem is usually circumvented by considering a notion of weak derivative and assigning the value $f'(0) = 0$, in such a way that $f'(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(x)$. Then, indeed, the primitive of $|x|$ turns out to be $\frac{1}{2}x|x|$, in accordance with your derivation.
